# Material sidenav causing problem with translate and flex css properties

Tags: html, css, electron, angular9, scss-mixins

So, currently working with my electron app having a sidenav structure like this:

```html
<!-- main container -->
<mat-drawer-container>
  <mat-drawer>parent sidenav</mat-drawer>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    parent content
    <mat-drawer-container>
      inside child container
      <mat-drawer>inside child sidenav</mat-drawer>
      <mat-drawer-content>
        inside child content
        <app-route>current problem occurs here</app-route>
      </mat-drawer-content>
    </mat-drawer-container>
  </mat-drawer-content>

</mat-drawer-container>
```

So, suppose at first route I'm having Html like this:

```html
<div class="box-empty-container">
  <div class="box-empty-msg">
    <div class="box-empty-logo"><span class="material-icons">info</span></div>
    <div class="box-empty-title">Nothing to show you here as your specified folders for checking music files are currently empty</div>
    <div class="box-empty-subtitle">Add new music search directories</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also scss:

```html
@mixin widthheight100{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%
}

.box-empty-container{
      position: relative;
      @include widthheight100() ;
      
      .box-empty-msg{
         position: absolute ;
         left: 50% ;
         top: 45% ;
         transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
         text-align: center;
       .box-empty-logo{
            span.material-icons{
               font-size: 2.5rem;
            }
       }
         
       .box-empty-title{
            font-family: 'jost-bold';
            font-size: 12pt;
       }
         
       .box-empty-subtitle{
            font-family: 'jost-regular';
            font-size: 10pt;
       }
}
```

[image: This is how it works in electron app on building]

I have tried to centralize `div.box-empty-msg` with both flex and translate method in scss and they are still not at center. When page loads this div is at center but when i open & close the sidenav it's position gets displaced form center. How can I solve this problem ?

**Edit:** Currently changed the scss style to `postion: absolute` strategy. [Link here for similar code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sxu6yg). It seems to work fine in stackblitz but in my actual project when screen size is large or medium the `div.box-empty-msg` is actually shifted some distance away from center. Also I think somehow in my project the sidenav is pushing the div tag away from center.

Comment: Can't run this to test, but probably with flexbox the `.box-empty-msg{ ..min-width, max-width..}` gets in the way. Seems redundant as you use `align-items and justify-content`, use some scaling `padding` instead. For `translate(-50%,-50%)` you would need `.box-empty-msg{ ..position: absolute..}`. Maybe post a [reprex]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ReneVanDerLende After thoroughly checking my project due to css properties set for `mat-drawer-content` as `{ width: 100% ; height: 100% }` it interfered with the styles of `box-empty-container`, hence shifting that slightly towards right.